# ¿Como pasar del usuario Postgres a otro usuario en el shell PSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Estoy logueado por consola dentro de una base Postgresql con el usuario postgres.
Tengo otro usuario en el cual quiero pararme, pero no encuentro que comando ejecutar por consola para hacer esto. Como pasar de un usuario al otro.
Logueado como posgres indico: `su - usuario2` y y no cambia.
Necesito que en la consola el usuario cambie de `postgres=# a usuario2=#`
Por supuesto tengo la password de usuario 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso no se puede hasta donde tengo entendido, debes desloguearte y volver a loguearte con el otro Usuario

```
psql -U NombreUsuario -d NombreBaseDatos
```

Comment: el comando que finalmente use es : psql -U usuario basededatos

Comment: el usuario es siempre el mismo, no son dos usuarios, es uno solo que pierde la conexión

Answer (score 1):

Si estás dentro de psql (PostgreSQL) puedes cambiarte entre bases de datos y usuarios con el meta-comando **\c** ó **\connect** sin tener que desconectarte o perder la sesión.

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo completo:

```
postgres@drakorod:~$ psql postgres postgres

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE mi_base; 
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# CREATE USER mi_usuario;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE USER otro_usuario;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \c mi_base mi_usuario
Ahora está conectado a la base de datos «mi_base» con el usuario «mi_usuario».
mi_base=> \c mi_base otro_usuario
Ahora está conectado a la base de datos «mi_base» con el usuario «otro_usuario».
mi_base=> \connect postgres mi_usuario
Ahora está conectado a la base de datos «postgres» con el usuario «mi_usuario».
postgres=>
```

Debes de verificar el nivel de acceso que tienes en el host en tu archivo pg_hba.conf pero eso sería otro tema que involucra otro tipo de requerimientos.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar de usuario, ingresas con el usuarios postgres y luego ejecutas el siguiente comando en la consola cambiando los datos por los de tu interes.

```
psql -d base_datos -U nombre_usuario -W
```

Saludos